# Analyzing Abs'[1]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, simplifying-expressions, numerics, complex

Version 12.1 on a Mac

The question about the derivative of `Abs'` has been asked several times, but all previous posts dealt with `Abs'[x]` and my question is about `Abs'[1]`.

It seems to me that there are no complex-numbers issues with `Abs'[1]`, yet

```
 Abs'[1]//N
```

does not simplify to 1.0. Is there a way to overcome this?

**Edit**:

For me, `Abs` appeared as a result of calling `Norm` on a real vector. How do I make it use `RealAbs`?

Comment: `1` is a complex number, too.  The problem is that `Abs[z]` is a complex function, not whether `z` is in the subset of real numbers.  In terms of complex function theory, `Abs'[z]` is undefined.  You can deal with it as it is dealt with elsewhere, such as `ComplexExpand[Abs'[1]]`.

Answer (score 10):

One must somehow assert the domain $\mathbb{R}$ because the default domain is $\mathbb{C}$.

The symbol [`RealAbs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealAbs.html) is one such way:

```
RealAbs'[1]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

---

Also note that just because there are no explicit complex numbers doesn't mean the derivative exists over $\mathbb{C}$. Here's the derivative at `z == 1` over both domains:

```
dq = DifferenceQuotient[Abs[z], {z, h}] /. z -> 1;

Limit[dq, h -> 0, Direction -> Complexes]
```

> ```
> Indeterminate
> ```

```
Limit[dq, h -> 0, Direction -> Reals]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies the behavior. But how does one make the following work: NIntegrate[D[Norm[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}], t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

Comment: You could define `RealNorm[args__] := Norm[args] /. Abs -> RealAbs`.

Comment: You could even remove some instance of `Abs` with `RealNorm[args__] := Norm[args] /. {Abs[f_]^n_Integer?EvenQ :> f^n, Abs[f_] :> RealAbs[f]}`